# Python - Pool map returns some dictionaries twice from method

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to use Python's `multiprocessing` to speed up a task of reading and processing data from a large `json` file. After processing the data, I need to write the new data to a new json file. However, the method returns some dictionaries twice or more and completely ignores other dictionaries (does not return them).

This method treats each `product` inside `products` and calls another function called func which will process the dictionary and return it to `p_entry_attributes`. If I print `p_entry_attributes` before returning it, it will print the correct dictionary but in the output file `import_file.json`, some dictionaries are repeated and some are not there.

```
def mainFunc(product):
    import_entry_file["entries"] = copy.deepcopy(import_entry_file["entries"])
    p_entry_attributes = copy.deepcopy(product_model)

    try:
        if (famille_produit == ""):
            p_entry_attributes = func(product, product_model)
            return p_entry_attributes

    except Exception as e:
        # Capture exception error log
        print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lock = mp.Lock()
    pool = Pool(initializer=setup, initargs=[lock])
    ent = pool.map(mainFunc, products)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    pool.terminate()

    import_entry_file["entries"] = []

    for ele in ent:
        import_entry_file["entries"].append(ele)

    with open("data/import_file.json", 'w', encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
        json.dump(import_entry_file, outfile, ensure_ascii=False)
```

This is the method func which modifies the dictionary and returns it.

```
def func(product, product_model):
    p_entry_attributes = product_model
    p_entry_attributes["fields"]["name"] = product["name"]
    p_entry_attributes["fields"]["id"] = product["id"]
    return p_entry_attributes
```

For e.g. if I have two `product`s of this format:

`{ 'name' : 'one', 'id' : '1'}` & `{ 'name' : 'two', 'id' : '2'}`

My output file will look like this:

```
{ "entries" : [ {"fields" : { "name" : "two", "id" : "2" }, { "name" : "two", "id" : "2"}} ]}
```

instead of:

```
{ "entries" : [ {"fields" : { "name" : "one", "id" : "1" }, { "name" : "two", "id" : "2"}} ]}
```

Comment: Are you sure that there is a problem with multiprocessing? Does it work differently when you call mainFunc(products) instead of pool.map(mainFunc, products)?

What is product_model? What is products used in pool.map call?

Btw, you don't need p_entry_attributes = copy.deepcopy(product_model) because you are not using it.

Comment: @magma Yes it works fine when I don't use pool.map. product_model is just a template json. Products is the list of products.

Answer (score 0):

Try `copy.deepcopy` in your function:

```
p_entry_attributes = copy.deepcopy(product_model)
```